# React - Component inside another component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I am building a small login form. I applied some global style in my `App.css`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: local('MyFont'), url(./fonts/raleway.ttf) format('woff');
}

body, html { 
  font-family: 'MyFont'
}
```

This is my **`App.js`**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar"
import Login from "./components/Login/Login"

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar/>
      <Login/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then I have a `Login` components (`src/components/Login/Login.js`) where I am importing a Button component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './Login.css'
import Button from "../Button/Button"


class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="section">
        <form>
          <h3>Log in</h3>

          [...]

          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                className="custom-control-input"
                id="customCheck1"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <Button type="submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my `Button` component (`src/components/Button/Button.js`)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './Button.css'


class Button extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <button>Login</button>
      );
    }
  }
  
  export default Button;
```

The button element does not use the style from App.js, the inherited style is override from something else as you can see on the picture. How can I fix this?
[image]

**button.css**

```
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
```

**login.css**

```
.section{
    background-color: pink;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}

.section form {
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

form input{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    resize: vertical;
    font-size: 15px;
  }

.form-group{
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
}
```

**computed tab**
[image]
[image]

Comment: so click at the Tab "Computed" in your dev-console and found those overwritten styles. There you see, which other style overwrites it (thats only as hint how you can found which style is overwriting another one). For the rest of your request, we need the real files that are used here... means what's about login.css, button.css ...?

Comment: I updated my post with correct css

Comment: what about the dev-console output for "Computed"? BTW: your button.css is written in capital letter, or lower-case?

Comment: I just added the computed tab to my post (end) thanks!

Comment: Works now with "*", amazing! The rest was working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set Font for the whole page, you better use `* {  font-family: Myfont;  }`
Make sure, MyFont is available and loaded.

Comment: Extra tip - I bet you want also use CSS Reset (normalize.css) just to make sure that browser doesn't apply some unwanted styles on top of your components.